# Determine digits decimal point

Tags: vb.net, decimal

I am working on this simple VB.net application that allows users to enter a decimal number (ex - 1.23) and the program lists what the digits are to the left and right of the decimal and as well as how many actual digits are to the left and right of the decimal. Here is what my code looks like so far.

> ```
> Dim imput As String
> imput = txtEnterNumber.Text
> Dim D As Integer
> D = txtEnterNumber.Text.IndexOf(".")
> txtNumLeft.Text = imput.Remove(D)
> txtNumRight.Text = imput.Remove(0, D)
> txtDigitLeft.Text = CStr(imput.Substring(0, D).Length)
> txtDigitRight.Text = CStr(imput.Substring(D).Length)
> ```

When I run my program it includes the decimal point for what the digits are to right of the decimal and as well as how many digits are right of the decimal. Why is this?

Thanks!

Comment: http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
Dim imput As String
imput = txtEnterNumber.Text
Dim D As Integer
D = txtEnterNumber.Text.IndexOf(".")
txtNumLeft.Text = imput.Remove(D)
txtNumRight.Text = imput.Remove(0, D + 1)
txtDigitLeft.Text = CStr(imput.Substring(0, D).Length)
txtDigitRight.Text = CStr(imput.Substring(D + 1).Length)
```

Comment: Thanks for getting back with me so quick! I'm getting the right values for the number of digits to the right of the decimal but the actual digits to the right of the decimal is still including the decimal point. (Ex - 1.23 as input. Number on the right: .23) 

Could you explain to me what you did above? Thanks!

Comment: I think I just figured it out. I added a +1 in the 6th line (0, D + 1) and now my program is working correctly. Thanks for all the help VK!

Answer (score 0):

Your substring is taking a substring from the decimal point, giving a `+1` position in `SUBSTRING` will solve it. Also, you can simplify your code using `SPLIT` function:

```
Dim num() as string = txtEnterNumber.Text.Split(".")
txtNumLeft.Text = num(0)
txtDigitLeft.Text = num(0).Length
If(num.Length > 1)Then 
  txtNumRight.Text = num(1)
  txtDigitRight.Text = num(1).Length
Else
  txtNumRight.Text = ""
  txtDigitRight.Text = 0
End If
```